# R installation of package to working directory

Tags: r, installation, r-package

I am having issues installing packages to my working directory.
I am trying to install the `AER` package.

I have set my working directory and checked it using `getwd()`. When I install the `AER` package, using `install.packages("AER")`, I get the option to choose 'Yes' or 'No', I then choose 'Yes', which shows this message:

```
Installing package into '/Users/tusharshahahni/Desktop'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies 'cli', 'rlang', 'lifecycle', 'scales', 'car'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.4.1              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
scales     1.1.1  1.2.1             FALSE
car       3.0-12  3.1-1             FALSE
AER        1.2-9 1.2-10             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

Followed by this warning:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'AER' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/cn/jsnjzyx54bjfk71l87vx9v800000gn/T/RtmpCKKBby/downloaded_packages'
```

This is what comes after I install the package. After this I am unable to access the package using `library(AER)`.

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: please provide the output of the `install.packages("AER")` command.

Comment: Welcome to SO Tushar! It's common for your package location and your working directory to be different. You can get these using .libPaths() and getwd().

Comment: If the question you chose yes to was "Do you want to install from the sources....", choose no. You get a simpler install for a small delay in getting the latest version.

Comment: `Installing package into '/Users/tusharshahahni/Desktop' (as 'lib' is unspecified) ` makes me wonder what your lib path is: can you run `.libPaths() ` please?